# Trouble storing an IMap with ArcObjects 10 and IPersistStream

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I'm storing a reference to an IMap in a custom object (which is stored by a custom extension) so that it can listen to map events. When I save the custom object using IPersistStream and then reload the MXD, it appears that I now have a reference to a COPY of the original IMap. I tested this by making a simple custom extension that saves the first IMap in the document... when reopening the saved MXD, the saved IMap != the first IMap in the document.

Is this how it should be working? Should I just be saving the location of the map in the document (rather than the actual IMap) and then resetting the reference during IPeristStream.Load?

I'm using C#, ArcGIS 10.0, and VS 2008.

Comment: What makes you think serializing and deserializing an object would give you the same object back? It will only *ever* be a copy of the original object. Given that, is that a problem for you, and if it is, how so? Also why does the map need to be persisted with the object? Why does an object that listens to events need to be persisted? Why can't you have one object specifically designed for the data that needs to be persisted, and other code to deal with events and references to other parts of the running ArcGIS app? What exactly is the purpose of the customizations? Can you share your code?

Comment: I suppose the point of all this is that something in the application needs to know which map to listen to when the MXD is opened again because data in my application is altered when layers are added and removed. If the answer is to simply store the location of the map rather than the map itself, that's fine. I was under the impression (based on something from the ESRI forums) that persisting something that was already persisted by the MXD itself would hold a reference to the same object that the MXD is storing. It sounds like that is incorrect.

Comment: I have not heard that so if you could cite it that would be great. I would expect that they would be two different object references. I agree that it makes more sense to store either the name or index of the map (data frame) than its entirety, or just make the assumption that it's always the first map in the MXD.

Comment: Ugh... I just did a quick search and I think I found what I had read. Reading it more closely, it was referring to the same object stored twice in a PropertySet referencing the same object vs different copies. Completely irrelevant to me.

Comment: I'll just store the index and all will be well. If there's a way to set this question as answered even though all the activity was in comments, let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd say just post a short answer of what you end(ed) up doing in the off chance it might help someone else down the road. You should have enough reputation now to post links, so I'd still like to see what you were referring to out of curiosity.

Comment: If you store two references to a single object in an ObjectStream, it will resolve itself on load as one object.  In your case, you are persisting to a separate stream outside the MXD so this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got back to this project and ended up storing the map index rather than the map itself. Works great. Thanks for the help.